# C# / Visual Studio 2017: References to functions got lost after updating / reorganizing the GUI

Tags: c#, visual-studio, user-interface

recently, I've reorganized some elements in my C#-GUI (move some buttons and dropdown-menus to another ribbon / ribbonbar). Somehow this lead to lost of references, such that the 'functions behind' the buttons / dropdown-menus can't be called right now.

My commit before I made this changes is fine (GUI-functions work). However, for the version after I introduced the new GUI-layout, it looks like nested functions does not get called properly. Well, the initial function still gets called after reorganization, i.e. the 'button_Click()', but the nested functions 'inside' seem partially not to work.
Does anyone give me please a hint on either how to avoid such a situation while restructuring the GUI in general or how I can find and fix all my missing refernces on a fast way?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Without some code it is impossible to guess what happens and help you with it.

Comment: WinForms or WPF?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your question, I would suggest that you can rebind the event to the moved control to make them can be called again.

Here is a code example you can refer to, which can use the moved control successfully.(I assume that it is a winform app)

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }

        private void MoveClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Hello!");
        }

        private void btnupdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 form2 = new Form2();
            form2.Show();
            Form2 form = (Form2)Application.OpenForms["Form2"];
            foreach (Control item in form.Controls)
            {
                if(item.Name=="btnmove")
                {
                    item.Click += MoveClick;
                }
            }
            
        }
    }
```

Also, we need to bind the event with Move button in the menu.

[image]

Tested result:
[image]

Comment: First of all, sorry for my late reply. @Jack J Jun - MSFT: That's it! Thank you so much! I just had to update the references / Event bindings manually after moving the items.